# output Map.Entry<Sentence, Integer> in descending order with java

Tags: java, sorting, printing, hashmap, output

Obviously this is a very naive attempt, but I'm quite inexperienced at programming. What I'd like to do is print these values in descending order, i.e. the biggest would print first and then smallest print last, how can I achieve this?

```
for (Map.Entry<Sentence, Integer> entry : ontology.ruleCount.entrySet()) 
    {
        if(entry.getValue() >= 10)
        System.out.println(entry.getKey()+" : "+entry.getValue());

        if(entry.getValue() >= 9)
            System.out.println(entry.getKey()+" : "+entry.getValue());

        if(entry.getValue() >= 8)
            System.out.println(entry.getKey()+" : "+entry.getValue());

        if(entry.getValue() >= 7)
            System.out.println(entry.getKey()+" : "+entry.getValue());

        if(entry.getValue() >= 6)
            System.out.println(entry.getKey()+" : "+entry.getValue());

        if(entry.getValue() >= 5)
            System.out.println(entry.getKey()+" : "+entry.getValue());

        if(entry.getValue() >= 4)
            System.out.println(entry.getKey()+" : "+entry.getValue());

        if(entry.getValue() >= 3)
            System.out.println(entry.getKey()+" : "+entry.getValue());

        if(entry.getValue() >= 2)
            System.out.println(entry.getKey()+" : "+entry.getValue());
    }
```

Comment: how about sorting the map? use treemap to sort store these values based on the sorted order of map values. comparator implementation sld help.

Comment: haha zerocool. hackers. awesome!

Comment: @zerocool It would be a very bad idea to sort map entries on a criterion which depends on anything else but the key. This would violate the essential assumptions the `TreeMap` is built on.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'll need to sort the collection of map entries. In Java 8 this takes quite simple code:

```
ontology.ruleCount.entrySet().stream()
        .sorted(reverseOrder(Map.Entry.comparingByValue()))
        .forEach(e -> System.out.println(e.getKey() + " : " + e.getValue()));
```

(implying `import static java.util.Collections.reverseOrder;`)

Comment: @BoristheSpider There, this version works. Strange, using `comparingByValue().reversed()` fails, but just inlining the code of `reversed`, which is `Collection.reverseOrder(this)`, works.

Comment: I'll have to add that one to my list of tricks. This is the right answer, +1.

Comment: brilliant! is there some kind of nice way to only print them out if the value if bigger than one?

Comment: That would be easy, just insert a filter stage before `sorted`: `.filter(e -> e.getValue() > 1)`.

Comment: what about to write them to a file rather than print them to the terminal? could i put a buffered writer in the place where you have the system.out.println?

Comment: @user3803974 `map` each item to a `String` rather than `foreach`, then `collect` to a `List<String>` and simply use [`Files.write`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#write-java.nio.file.Path-java.lang.Iterable-java.nio.file.OpenOption...-).

Comment: could I just pipe the output to a file? is that possible in eclipse?

Comment: @BoristheSpider I've [made a question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28137421/failure-to-infer-type-at-an-unexpected-place-possible-javac-bug) out of this inference issue right away :)

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik excellent, starred. Hopefully someone can get to the bottom of it.

Comment: @user3803974 You certainly can replace `System.out` with any other `PrintStream` (although preferrably you'll use a `PrintWriter`).

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik yea I did that, I like that way it's easy, though later I'll probably try to do as Boris suggested

Comment: @user3803974 in production code I would actually prefer the approach where values are printed without the need to first materialize the complete output on the heap.

Comment: what does that mean 'materialize on the heap', is it if you pipe it you use less memory because java doesn't have to save them and then write them out one by one, something like that?

Answer (score 2):

`Entry.comparingByValue().reversed` doesn't work in sorting a map according to values in descending order. Here is an easy solution

```html
  UnSortedMap.entrySet().stream()
                    .filter(e -> e.getValue() > 1)
                    .sorted(Entry.comparingByValue(Comparator.reverseOrder()))
                    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue,
                            (e1, e2) -> e1, LinkedHashMap::new));
```

Answer (score 0):

The basic procedure (pre-Java 8) is:

1. Write the elements of `ontology.ruleCount.entrySet()` into a `List`, e.g. an `ArrayList`.
2. Implement a suitable [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) which looks at the entries' values
3. Use [`Collections.sort`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator)) to sort your `List` using the `Comparator`.
4. Use the sorted list however you like!

Comment: how to make Collections.sort order things to be descending?

Comment: Implement your comparator to give the desired ordering, e.g. `return -Integer.compare(first value, second value);` or `return Integer.compare(second value, first value);`

Comment: how to make sure it prints only one entry per line?

Comment: Make one call to `System.println` per entry.