# Failure to infer type at an unexpected place (possible javac bug?)

Tags: java, java-8, type-inference

While answering a question I encountered this strange behavior of Java's type inference. The following works without trouble:

```
new HashMap<String,Integer>().entrySet().stream()
                             .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue());
```

but if we just add `.reversed()` at the end, it suddenly fails:

```
new HashMap<String,Integer>().entrySet().stream()
                             .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue().reversed());
```

Detail: in the first case, the type of `comparingByValue()` is inferred as `Comparator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>`, but in the second case it changes to `Comparator<Map.Entry<Object, V>>`.

The type of `reversed()` is simply `Comparator<T>`—an identity transformation on the type of its target. How come type inference loses it on such a seemingly trivial step? I cannot escape the hunch that this must be due to a bug in the inferring mechanics.

As a further conundrum, if we just inline the implementation of `reversed()`, which is `return Collections.reverseOrder(this);`:

```
new HashMap<String,Integer>().entrySet().stream()
                             .sorted(reverseOrder(Map.Entry.comparingByValue());
```

it works again.

Comment: May this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27205309/misunderstanding-about-comparator-in-java-8 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25172595/comparator-reversed-not-compiles-using-lambda It also surprises me (as I asked the question), but it seems that it's a weakness in the type inference mechanism. So deal with it for the moment :-)

Comment: @user2336315 with input from Jon Skeet and Brian Goetz (!). Good finds.

Comment: I'm closing my own question as a duplicate of the one with user Holger's answer because I find that answer the most relevant and complete. Even the answer from Stuart Marks (also a member of the core Java team) states that he is not entirely sure why this happens :) What is clear is that inference fails in the method receiver position, a fact perfectly aligned with my finding.