# Why can I not reverse a comparator in a Java 8 stream which compares by map value?

Tags: java, java-stream

This statement...:

```
singletonMap("key", "value")
    .entrySet()
    .stream()
    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry::getValue))
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

prints all map entries sorted by the value in the map. While pointless for a map with only a single entry, it compiles. However if I want the reverse and I try:

```
singletonMap("key", "value")
    .entrySet()
    .stream()
    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry::getValue).reversed())
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

I get the following compilation error:

```
Error:(100, 85) java: incompatible types: cannot infer type-variable(s) T,U
    (argument mismatch; invalid method reference
      method getValue in interface java.util.Map.Entry<K,V> cannot be applied to given types
        required: no arguments
        found: java.lang.Object
        reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
Error:(100, 89) java: invalid method reference
  non-static method getValue() cannot be referenced from a static context
```

What happend here that the `.reversed()` changed so much?

Comment: This is a known bug - finding the link now. Use [`Collections.reverseOrder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverseOrder-java.util.Comparator-).

Comment: See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28137421/2071828)

Comment: @BoristheSpider: Is it? If you describe the background of the bug, maybe add a link to some kind of ticket, that would be a good answer I can accept :-).

Comment: Already covered on SO...